# PyTorch: what is d_model in Transfomer?

Tags: pytorch

Doc:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html

```
torch.nn.Transformer(d_model=512, nhead=8, num_encoder_layers=6, num_decoder_layers=6, dim_feedforward=2048, ...)

Parameters
d_model (int) – the number of expected features in the encoder/decoder inputs (default=512).
```

When translating, what's the relationship between `sequence_length`, `vocabulary_size`, and `d_model`?

For example, when translating **English(source)** to **Spanish(target)**,

```
English: src_sequence_length=400, src_vocabulary_size=40000
Spanish: tgt_sequence_length=300, tgt_vocabulary_size=30000
```

how to set the `d_model` value and other parameters in the code below? what are the shapes of `src` and `tgt`? what is the shape of `out`?

```
>>> transformer_model = nn.Transformer(d_model=???)
>>> src = torch.rand((batch_size, ??, ??))
>>> tgt = torch.rand((batch_size, ??, ??))
>>> out = transformer_model(src, tgt)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html) it states the following:

- src: `(S,E)` for unbatched input, `(S,N,E)` if `batch_first=False` or `(N, S, E)` if `batch_first=True`.
- tgt: `(T,E)` for unbatched input, `(T,N,E)` if `batch_first=False` or `(N, T, E)` if `batch_first=True`.
- Note: Default is (sequence, batch, feature)
- Note: `S` is source sequence length, `T` is target sequence length, `N` is batch size and `E` is number of features.

With this we can answer your question (assuming batched input and the default of `batch_first=False`):

```
num_features = 512 # default value

>>> transformer_model = nn.Transformer(d_model=num_features)
>>> src = torch.rand((source_seq_len, batch_size, num_features))
>>> tgt = torch.rand((target_seq_len, batch_size, num_features))
>>> out = transformer_model(src, tgt)
```

You mix properties of the transformer with properties of a dataset. A dataset has a vocab size and is usually subject to these preprocessing steps:

1. Remove words from vocabulary that are very infrequent
2. Learn a word embedding (use a pretrained word embedding)
3. Result from 2. is a vector representation for each word with an embedding dimension of, say 512 (which is `d_model=num_features`).

I hope I could clarify the Transformer inputs and the misunderstanding that vocab size is a parameter that is related to the transformer when it is only related to the dataset.